Firebase and Google cloud billing problem
I am unable to add billing account to firebase and cloud console. What are the main requirements for google cloud console?
I have tried so many Card  for billing account but every times it show error.
This action couldn't be completed. Try again later.[OR_BACR2_34]

Payment methods you can add to your Google payments profile
